# How do specify a polymorphic default for `next` in Python?

Tags: python, types

Suppose I have a variable

```py
something: AnyStr = next(some_iterator, "")
```

This (as expected) causes MyPy to raise an error, because if `AnyStr` has type `bytes` this causes a problem because next will return a default value which is a `str` (so a `Union[str, bytes]`).

Is there a way to specify the default in such a way that the type checker wouldn't raise an error here? My suspicion is that it's not possible because types are in the statics of the program, whereas the behaviour I want would change the dynamics of my program?

Comment: `AnyStr` is an unbound type variable. `next` isn't (as far as I can tell) type-hinted, so `mypy` has no idea what it will return, and thus which type to bind to `AnyStr`.

Comment: You want to use `Union[str, byte]` instead of `AnyStr`.